# Where can I find Neloth's apprentice?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I cannot find Talvas Fathryon in Tel Mithryn. I never used him as a follower and have completed all quests for Neloth with the exception of his radiant quests. Any idea where he could be? I need him to buy spell tomes that i cannot find anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

With all of Neloth's quests completed *up to* Briarheart Necropsy, including the Reluctant Steward quest, Talvas can be found in the main room of **Tel Mithryn** 24 hours a day (tested by waiting).  More often than not he is peering down the magical lift from the railings.

This is after his own personal quest of "From the Ashes" is completed outside Tel Mithryn - before this point he remains outside the compound.